# How to increase the performance of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

Holiday (table)

```
dates

2012-08-02 
2012-08-19 
2012-08-20
```

Table1

```
id dates time

001 01/08/2012 00:00
001 02/08/2012 00:00
001 03/08/2012 00:00
001 04/08/2012 12:00
...
...
001 17/04/2012 11:00
001 18/08/2012 00:00
001 19/08/2012 00:00
001 20/08/2012 00:00
001 21/08/2012 12:00
...
```

I want to check previous date and next date of each column, then I want to update present or absent or holiday.

Condition's

- If current row time is not equal to 00:00 then status should be `P` (Present)
- If previous date time column is 00:00 and next date time column is 00:00 then automatically current row status should be `AB` (Absent),
- If dates is equal to holiday table date then automatically current row status should be `H`

Note: this query is running witout any fail, only concern is time consuming...

Query

```
Select 
    t2.id, 
    t2.dates, 
    case 
        when t2.time <> '00:00' 
            then 'P' 
        when t4.dates = t2.dates and t1.intime = '00:00' and t3.intime = '00:00' 
            then 'AB' 
        else 'H' 
    end as attn 
from
    (
        Select id, dates, time from table1 
        where t1.dates = Cast('18/08/2012' as datetime)
    ) t1 
    left outer join
    (
        Select id, dates, time from table1 
        where t2.dates = Cast('19/08/2012' as datetime)
    ) t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id
    left outer join 
    (
        Select id, dates, time from table1 
        where t2.dates = Cast('20/08/2012' as datetime)
    ) t3 
    on t2.id = t3.id
    left outer join 
    (
        select dates from holiday
    ) t4 
    on t4.dates = t2.dates
```

The above query is working fine, but it was taking more time to display because I want to view the data from `01/09/2012` to `30/09/2012` for each `id`, i have n number of id,
system is checking previous date and next date for each id and showing the result.

Any other alternative query or solution is there for displaying the data

Comment: is this homework ? why wouldn't use joins ?

Comment: @ElVieejo, Ya i want to use joins...

Answer (score 1):

as Gordon said, your structure is fine, but I can recommend you another way in order to improve the performance of this query (or any other heavy one) which is to use **Database Engine Tuning Advisor**.

using this tool, SQL server will try to create additional indexes, statistics, and anything else that could improve the performance of the provided query.

to launch it, select your query text from the query window, right click, then choose **Analyze Query in Database Engine Tuning Advisor**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You basic query structure is fine.  Personally, I wouldn't hardcode the dates in the subquery, instead adding the date into the "on" clause.

You can make this run faster by creating an index on (id, date):

```
create index table1_id_date on table1(id, date)
```

And index on holiday might also help:

```
create index holiday_date on holiday(date)
```

You could also upgrade to a more recent version of SQL Server.  Your query would be faster and much easier to express in SQL Server 2012, because of the lag() and lead() functions.